# Is this phrase used anywhere in real world "too startled to say something"

Tags: grammaticality, learning, some-any

I got this question in one of my mock tests for an exam.
[image: screenshot]

*Click on the image to enlarge*

> She was too startled at first **saying something**, but finally she blurted out the truth.

The website correctly points out that **to say** must be used in the place of **saying**. But I feel that **something** should also be replaced with **anything**. I feel that we need an extra word (probably adjective) after **something** and before the comma for the sentence to be correct.

> She was too startled to say something smart, but finally blurted out the truth.

Even that doesn't sit well with the second part of the sentence.

Using **anything** feels much better. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'd mark C wrong and A correct.

Comment: Someone please help me choose relevant tags.

Comment: I don't like cut-and-pasted exam questions (which are really not for this site)  but especially don't like **7 or lower fonts**. Geesus.

Comment: @Lambie That's why I had typed the details below the picture.

Comment: You left out the verb say in your sentence with the paragraph mark, and it's "Even that doesn't sit well etc."

Comment: And, fyi, you can put this structure in your mental closet: too [adjective] to [verb], as a general proposition. And something and anything are slightly different. anything is slightly more negative as it is often used with negative verbs: I didn't say anything.

Comment: Likely it would be _anything_ rather than _something_; otherwise it's fine. _Too_ is a negative trigger and would normally take a negative polarity item like _anything_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following many decades of native English usage, I can tell you that both A and C would be considered correct. If anything A is more correct than C. "Anything" is more usually used rather than "something" in negative contexts:

> I did not say anything.

is preferred over

> I did not say something.

But your sentence isn't quite the same, and everybody I know would consider "too started to say something" to be unquestionably acceptable.

Given that the focus of the explanation is on "to" versus "too", but there is no option that includes a "too", I wonder if there is a mistake in the question and either answer A or C was meant to read "too say something/anything".

**TLDR: If your exam is testing your ability to speak formally correct English like a native, then A should be a correct answer, probably along with C.**